# Seeing latest results in Kibana after the page limit is reached

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to logstash. I have set up my logstash to populate elastic search and have Kibana read out of it. The problem I am facing is that after the

```
number of records = results per page x page limit
```

the UI stops getting new results. Is there a way to set Kibana up such that it discards the old results instead of the latest after the limit is reached?

Comment: this looks like you should open a bug in their issue tracker

Answer (score 0):

To have kibana read the latest results, reload the query.

To have more pages available (or more results per page), edit the panel.

Make sure the table is reverse sorted by @timestamp.